# Intersecting Node A and Node B columns for lines table

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have one view (LineString) and one table(Point). Some line features intersect with some points at the beginning and end nodes. I'd like to create another view and have columns named *"node_a" and "node_b"*. I have tried the following query which produced one row for node A and one row for node B and linestring ID for each.

```
SELECT
    a.geometry AS linestring,
    a."ID" AS point_a,
    b."ID" AS point_b
FROM
    pia.or_chamber AS a
JOIN
    pia.design_pia AS b
ON
    ST_Intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry)
WHERE
    a."ID" < b."ID"; -- To avoid duplicate pairs
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

But my aim is to create following table which I can achieve that using the following virtual field formulas on qgis but as the points table is big it takes a while and computer resource to calculate it

```
overlay_intersects('or_chamber_68a0c2c5_ac84_4696_959e_082cc0e4eb76', "ID")[0]
overlay_intersects('or_chamber_68a0c2c5_ac84_4696_959e_082cc0e4eb76', "ID")[1]
```

**OUTPUT from QGIS**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Judging from the table presented as "OUTPUT from QGIS", the result should be unique on column "ID" which, when compared to the "OUTPUT" above, is actually column b."ID". The values in columns "node_a" and "node_b" are then the "ID" values from two different linestrings from table pia.oc_chamber (so node_a and node_b actually come from the table with alias "a"). In other words: if a point in table design_pia is a start point or an end point of 1 or 2 linestrings, you appear to want to know which linestrings (i.e. which linestring ID's) those might be, with the lower ID-value in column "node_a" and the higher ID-value (if present) in column "node_b".

The JOIN can indeed be time consuming. Since the intersecting points, according to your description, must be start and end points of the linestring, it is possible to join directly on those points (therefore each point does not need to be checked against the entire linestring, but only on the two ending points of each linestring). The boundary of a linestring is defined as the start point and end point, so we can use postgis function ST_Boundary on a linestring, which returns a MultiPoint geometry, containing just those two points.

Using ST_Intersects would work, but ST_Within might be slightly more efficient (it needs to perform fewer background checks -- and as a check on boundaries is unnecessary on Point geometries, since points do not have boundaries, `ST_Relate(a.geom, b.geom 'T*F******')` uses fewer checks still, but will not make use of any geometry index if present).

Your preferred result in "OUTPUT from QGIS" does not say if any geometry should be obtained but, since rows are unique on ID's from the points table, I presume that those points will be needed. Where all the other columns come from I cannot tell (possibly also from the points table? I'm not sure) so I have disregarded them in the following example:

```
SELECT "ID", geometry, node[1] AS node_a, node[2] AS node_b, geometry
FROM (
  SELECT b."ID", b.geometry, array_agg(DISTINCT a."ID" ORDER BY a."ID") AS node
  FROM
    pia.or_chamber AS a
  JOIN
    pia.design_pia AS b
  ON
    ST_Within(b.geometry, ST_Boundary(a.geometry))
  GROUP BY b."ID", b.geometry
) AS temp;
```

It does the following:

- in subquery "temp" the points from table "b" are collected, as long as they intersect (are actually ST_Within) the MultiPoint that represents the endpoints of the linestring from table "a";
- that can lead to multiple intersections (a point may be an endpoint of two linestrings, or more than two if those linestrings form a network), and from all those intersecting linestrings the "ID"s are stored in an array (sorted by ID);
- in the main SELECT only the first two ID's are retrieved from the array, where the lower value is presented in column "node_a" and the next value in column "node_b";
- if a point intersects with only 1 linestring (array "node" has length 1), the value for array element node[2] will be NULL (conforming to the given sample output).

Should, after testing, the JOIN still be slow, one might also try the following adjustment of the ON condition:

```
ON b.geometry = ANY (ARRAY[ST_StartPoint(a.geometry), ST_EndPoint(a.geometry)])
```

This stores the start point and end point of the linestring in an array (of type geometry[]) and uses the ANY operator to check whether b.geometry is equal to either of those two points. This requires even fewer background checks than ST_Intersects, ST_Within or ST_Relate and, as far as I can remember, the `= ANY (ARRAY ...)` construction is slightly more efficient than the more common  `IN (...)` construction.

Answer (score 2):

You need an outer join vs inner join - inner join removes non-matching rows from the join table.  Left outer join keeps all the rows from the left table (pia.or_chamber):

```
SELECT
    a.geometry AS linestring,
    a."ID" AS point_a,
    b."ID" AS point_b
FROM
    pia.or_chamber AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    pia.design_pia AS b
ON
    ST_Intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) and a."ID" != b."ID";
```

Comment: That generated the same output as the first table

Comment: try FULL OUTER JOIN?  It's not super clear what you want as the output.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want to get start and end node information for your LineStrings?

I.e. something like

```
SELECT
  oc.*,
  sn."ID" AS start_node,
  en."ID" AS end_node
FROM
  pia.or_chamber AS oc
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      p."ID"
    FROM
      pia.design_pia AS p
    WHERE
      ST_StartPoint(oc.geometry) && p.geometry
      -- ST_DWithin(ST_StartPoint(oc.geometry), p.geometry, <small_threshold>)
  ) AS sn ON TRUE
  LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      p."ID"
    FROM
      pia.design_pia AS p
    WHERE
      ST_EndPoint(oc.geometry) && p.geometry
      -- ST_DWithin(ST_EndPoint(oc.geometry), p.geometry, <small_threshold>)
  ) AS sn ON TRUE
;
```

Here we efficiently find the intersecting `pia.design_pia.geometry` both for the `ST_StartPoint` and `ST_EndPoint` of each `pia.or_chamber.geometry`, if present, by an index-powered check for intersecting *bounding boxes* (`&&` - the bbox of a `POINT` *is* itself). Alternatively, use the out-commented `ST_DWithin` check with a small distance threshold if points are not exactly equal.

As mentioned, this benefits ***massively*** from a `GIST` index on `pia.design_pia.geometry`!